# Xcode 11.3 does not have latest iOS version

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, xcode11.3

Any reason the latest version of iOS is not available in the update version of Xcode ? 13.3 is missing and this allowed for me to upload a tested version of an application which was subsequently approved and then once released caused a crash. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the latest BETA release of Xcode and that has 13.3 as well as 13.4.
The current stable release of Xcode allows my code to build but it will not pass approval in the store because of the missing SDK. Just be aware of this should you have a similar issue.